# Socket.io can't change a global variable in socket.on

Tags: node.js, socket.io, global

I use Node.js, Express and socket.io.

**I can't change a global variable in the socket.on function.**

It's strange because i managed to do it before but now it bugs and i don't know why.
There is a simple answer but it doesnt work : 16270997

Can you help me please ?

---

*Server :*

```
   var express = require('express');
   var app = express.createServer();
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/tank/'));
  var server = app.listen(8080);

  var socket = require("socket.io");
  var io = socket.listen(server);

  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
      socket.emit('con');
   });
```

*Client :*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var socket = io.connect();  
var id = 1;

socket.on('con', function () {
   id++;
   alert(id); // it displays 2
});

alert(id);  // it displays 1

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are triggering the outer `alert` even before the `con` messages gets received and `id++` gets executed.

You can check this by

```
var socket = io.connect();  
var id = 1;

socket.on('con', function () {
   id++;
   alert(id); // it displays 2
   printGlobalIdvalue(); // prints global variable
});

function printGlobalIdvalue() {
    alert(id);  // it also displays 2
}
```